# reshape dataframe by splitting row using plyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to split a dataframe row into segments (length 3) and recombine the segments using dplyr or plyr?

```
temp<-rbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(7,8,9,0,0,0))
matrix(temp,ncol=3,byrow=F) #Fails
```

Goal

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
0 0 0
```

Comment: You need to transpose it first. matrix(as.vector(t(temp)),ncol=3,byrow=T)

Comment: Looks like your goal is not to split by row based on the expected output

Comment: @mr.joshuagordon, that was what I needed. Can you propose that as an answer with an explanation of why the transpose was necessary?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823211/how-to-convert-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array-in-r.

Comment: should I close the question?