# How to move up the values of each column in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, triangular

I'm looking for a general way to do the following,
I have a triangular matrix of nxn, for example:

```
a NA NA
b  d NA
c  e f
```

and convert it in:

```
a d f
b e NA
c NA NA
```

The idea is: for each column move the values, until the first non-NA value is in the first row

I imagine that it is done with a for, for each column, so that it goes up, but I do not know how to make it ...

Comment: It's a good idea to be more precise about this "going up". The first column shifts by one position, while the second one by two. Is it about shifting until the first non-NA value?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit my question and yes, it's about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with a custom function -

```
m <- structure(c("a", "b", "c", NA, "d", "e", NA, NA, "f"), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3")))

custom_shift <- function(x) {
  y <- x[!is.na(x)]
  length(y) <- length(x)
  y
}

apply(m, 2, function(a) custom_shift(a))

     V1  V2  V3 
[1,] "a" "d" "f"
[2,] "b" "e" NA 
[3,] "c" NA  NA
```

Comment: but I only have the matrix, no the vector

Comment: Both, input `m` and output, in my solution are matrix. I am not using any vector. Just run the code and let me know.

Comment: I found this, thank u :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823211/convert-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Fixed it to not sort the values:

```
apply(m, 2, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])
```

**Original:** Another solution which uses `sort(..., na.last = T)` and is good if you need each column to be sorted:

```
m <- structure(c("a", "b", "c", NA, "d", "e", NA, NA, "f"), .Dim = c(3L, 
                                                                     3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3")))

apply(m, 2, sort, na.last = T )

     V1  V2  V3 
[1,] "a" "d" "f"
[2,] "b" "e" NA 
[3,] "c" NA  NA
```

Comment: by sorting, you are changing the order in which they appear. Although am not quite sure whether that is an issu

Comment: Isn't that the desired output? At the very least, it matches OP's second table. However, I agree that I wouldn't want to change the order as at that point, why have the matrix if the column row order doesn't matter?

Comment: this case it is matching because d<e otherwise if we had d in the 3rd and e in the second, I d not think it will give the output. Its fine. I am not the one who asked the question

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, you're right. I'll work on an edit or delete.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I fixed it to sort on whether it's NA or not. This shouldn't change the order.